# How to make the fields prefilled in tab B, after entering the fields in tab A using angular2 or typescript

Tags: angular

i fill the fields in tab A and saves it.. When i open the tab B, i want it to get prefilled.. can anyone help me to solve this.
i am here by sharing my html and ts code.

**HTML:**

```
<label>Tables</label>
                                <ng-select name="table" [options]="" [(ngModel)]="entry.table" placeholder="table" required>
                                </ng-select>
```

**Ts code:**

```
this.ApiService
      .getTab(d.tabA_id)
      .subscribe(
        tables  => {
          this.tables = tables.map(function(table) 
            return {"value":table,"label":table.tableName};
          })
```

Comment: do you want the data in select element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like:

**In HTML**

```
<select name="table" [(ngModel)]="selectedTableData" required>       
  <option *ngFor="let table of tables" [value]="table.value">
   {{table.value}}
  </option>
</select>
```

**`ApiService` code:**

```
 public getTab(id) {
        return this.http.get(url, {id:id})
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(*handleError code*);
    }
```

**then in Component :**

```
this.apiService.getTab(d.tabA_id).subscribe(result => this.tables=result);
```